# Is it possible to make HTTP requests from angular running on a valid HTTPS endpoint

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ssl, https

I have angular running on port 443 with its respective certificates all in place.

I now need to make local requests but using HTTP and not HTTPS.

When angular makes a request, even though the route defined is HTTP it forces it to HTTPS.

Is there a way around this?

This is a temporary solution, ideally, we would have the net core service running with HTTPS, but the version is 2.1.3 and it is weird that the method UseHSTS is not available and when we try to install the respective NuGet we get an incompatibility issue.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Mike, how do you define HTTP? Did you uncheck `Enable SSL` in Project properties? Also, you could remove `UseHttpsRedirection` middleware in Startup.cs.

Comment: That is also one method that is entirely not available. I have now tried to update the project to version 3.0. I am now evaluating if everything is working... Might be the better solution, if I can keep the updated project version.